# C# Fill GridView with Function

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a gridview that i want to fill with data from my linq to sql file.

I tried to create a function to fill a gridview with a string that its the table name.

```
InformitoDataContext db = new InformitoDataContext();

    public void FillGridView(string Table, Control GridView) 
    {
        var ds = from q
              in db.Table //Error in db.Table: 'InformitoDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Table'
                select q;
        (GridView as GridView).DataSource = ds;
        (GridView as GridView).DataBind();
    }
```

And it should be working like this:

```
 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Data.FillGridView("news", GridView1);
}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: When you know it is a gridview, why do you declare input param as Control instead of GridView

Comment: Wich is the difference between __(string Table, GridView GridView)__ and __(string Table, Control GridView)__ ?

Comment: @xRed When you have it as control you have to cast further down (GridView as GridView) - For conventional purposes and to make it implicitly typed change the parameters to (string table, GridView gv) and then gv.DataSource = ds; etc.

Comment: @xRed also when you say a LINQ to SQL file I take it you mean entity framework?

Comment: @LukeHennerley no, the old and discontinued LinqToSql Class from VisualStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using reflexion:

```
public void FillGridView(string Table, Control GridView) 
{
    var property = typeof(InformitoDataContext).GetProperty(Table);
    IQueryable query = (IQueryable)(property.GetGetMethod().Invoke(db, new object[0]));
    (GridView as GridView).DataSource = query;
    (GridView as GridView).DataBind();
}
```

But this is not something I would recommend... you are linking objects to strings though linq to SQL is doing the exact contrary...

Well... I did not test the code, it may not compile... this is just to get the idea

Comment: It gives this error when compiling: __Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)__

Answer (score 1):

pass the connection string in the constructor of InformitoDataContext

```
string str= /*connection string*/
InformitoDataContext db = new InformitoDataContext(str);
```

try it.

Comment: @mitali, thats not the problem. Its in the function, not the connection.

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove uppercase at the beginning of your variables:

```
public void FillGridView(string table, GridView gridView) 
    {
        var ds = from q in table;
        select q;
        gridView.DataSource = ds;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Yes ? how will this solve the issue ? xRed has coding rules that may differ from yours. they are not bad only for this reason

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem. it just creates a gridview with the string i entered, separated by chars